# WFS intersect filter with multiple polygons

Tags: polygon, wfs, gml

I am trying to do a WFS POST request to https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/crow-act-2000-section-4-conclusive-registered-common-land-england/wfs where I need to send a list of polygons and find out if any of them are intersecting with the layers found on the endpoint.
I have done the [GetCapabilities](https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/crow-act-2000-section-4-conclusive-registered-common-land-england/wfs/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities) check so I know that it can accept `gml:Polygon`.

This is my request body so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wfs:GetFeature maxFeatures="5000" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" resultType="hits" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
    <wfs:Query typeName="ms:Crow_Act_2000_Section_4_Conclusive_Registered_Common_Land_England">
       <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:Intersects>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700">
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList>352722 488465 505172 482115 558353 140008 304353 111433 352722 488465</gml:posList>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </ogc:Intersects>
                <ogc:Intersects>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700">
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList>289146 331504 289148 331824 289535 331814 289516 331502 289146 331504</gml:posList>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </ogc:Intersects>
            </ogc:Or>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And the error that I get back looks like this:

```
<ExceptionReport
 version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd"
>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Or' : operand is wrong.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Intersects' can only be one per filter request.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Or' : operand is wrong.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Unknown system error.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

I am not sure why it is having a problem with the `ogc:Or`, as this same request body works for a different endpoint (https://datamap.gov.wales/geoserver/wfs) though this other request body does have a different `typeName` and `PropertyName`.
Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to why it is not working with the multiple polygons on an Intersects filter query?

Comment: Not that you can do much about this, but looking at the WFS 1.1.0 query in a validator there are two issues.  The first is that you need to have a namespace declaration for the `ms` prefix for the featureType `xmlns:ms="https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/crow-act-2000-section-4-conclusive-registered-common-land-england/wfs"` the second issue is the validator tells me that the typename attribute value isn't valid! ~ `is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '((\w:)?\w(=\w)?){1,}' for type 'TypeNameListType'.`

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but I think you may be mixing versions somewhere, as you seem to be asking for a version 1.1.0 service but reference FES (which is WFS 2.0).

```
<wfs:GetFeature maxFeatures="5000" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" resultType="hits" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
```

Did you specify a version in the URL you POST to? I think your client is confused/confusing the server. Try making it a 2.0.0 request and using the FES or make it a 1.1.0 and be specific in the end point.

The reason the 2nd end point works is because it is a cheap open source program (GeoServer) rather than a very expensive proprietary server (ESRI).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking a look at my question, I tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately it didn't work. I suspect you are correct and it is an issue with the source.

I have managed to find an alternative source which uses ESRI ( https://services.arcgis.com/JJzESW51TqeY9uat/ArcGIS/rest/services) and I can do the intersects check that I require with that source.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).